# Restrict mosquitto MQTT publisher to just one IP address

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm not sure if this is possible from the conf file but it should be. I don't care what network subscribers come from... .i.e what ip address/network adapter the subscribers connect to but I only want 127.0.0.1 or another network adapter (like an openVPN virtual adapter) to be able to publish messages.
Is that achievable with mosquitto?

Comment: I hope you don't think that this will make your MQTT connection secure. IP addresses are easily spoofed. This is no replacement for actual security using usernames and passwords, or certificates.

Comment: (and over an encrypted connection)

Comment: You reckon somehow a spoofed IP address will appear on my VPN adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. This is normally something you would do via usernames to identify a user that can publish and then deny publishing to anonymous users.

You may be able to effectively achieve what you want by using the `per_listener_settings` setting to attach different ACL files to each listener and have a specific listener for the lo interface.

The problem with this is you would need to have listeners for every interface and I'm not sure how it would behave with interfaces that may not be present at startup (e.g. a vpn adapter)

```
per_listener_settings true

listener 1883 127.0.0.1
acl_file /path/acl_allow_publish

listener 1883 192.168.0.1
acl_file /path/acl_allow_only_subscribe
```